# Overwrite machine.config oracle.manageddataaccess.client version setting at app.config C#

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, config, managed

**Edit:**

**To be more clear, My question is how to overwrite machine.config setting from app.config for `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` without modify machine.config.
I have to do that is because Visual studio EntityFramework Wizard/Server Explorer relay on machine level setting.**

I have to config/register oracle.ManagedDataAccess on machine level in order to make Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework work with Visual studio 2015 (Is this true? Is there another way?).

Otherwise, I got following error on my .edmx file , and can't view model or connect to database , even from Server Explorer.

```
Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
```

The problem I have is that the oracle configure not only add the dll into GAC,
It also add a following entry into my machine.config file.

```
<version number="4.121.2.0">
      <settings>
        <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="*my oracle home*\odp.net\managed\x86\..\..\..\network\admin" />
      </settings>
    </version>
```

Which is a problem when I indeed using version 4.121.2.0 and want to change that on application level.

What I want to do is to overwrite my machine.config setting in my app.config use following instead of mess around with my machine.config file

```
 <version number="*">
            <settings>
                <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\OtherPalce\Oracle" />
            </settings>
```

Can not find any document that show me how to do that.

Is there a `<clear>` tag that supported under tag `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>`

Or something else like add `<remove version number="*">` on top.

Comment: Note sure what your problem is but you can edit the config file with every simple text editor.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm ?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but <remove> and <clear> not work: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/3708